# Show all options with many-to-many and many-to-one

Tags: sql-server

I have inherited a database the following relationships:

`Product >--< Option --< OptionValue`

So, for example, a `Desk` might have `Colour`, `Width`, and `Height` as Options, with `Colour={Oak,Beech,Walnut}`, `Width={90cm,110cm,150cm}` and `Height={60cm,75cm,90cm}`

This is models as a M:N, 1:N, and is normalised (i.e. `Product`, `ProductOption`, `Option`, and `OptionValue` all have the expected PKs and FKs).

The requirement is to get all combinations of `Option` for each `Product`.

I'm essentially thinking this is an EAV schema in disguse, but I'd be happy for someone to humour me.

Previously, there were a limited number of options per product, so I could use a PIVOT and left joins (and make dbas around the world cry), but the requirements have changed to allow an unlimited number of options per Product.

Comment: do you expect one column per Option + one column per OptionValue?

Comment: or something like this: `Width={90cm,110cm,150cm}`?

Comment: Either will do - in fact the latter might be easier to consume by the client app

Answer (score 1):

Given this sample:

```
CREATE TABLE #Products (ProductId int, Name varchar(200));
insert into #Products values
(1, 'Desk'),
(2, 'Table');

CREATE TABLE #Options(OptionId int, ProductId int, Name varchar(200));
insert into #Options values
(1, 1, 'Colour'),
(2, 1, 'Weight'),
(3, 2, 'Colour'),
(4, 2, 'Width');

CREATE TABLE #OptionsValues(OptoinValueId int, OptionId int, Name varchar(200));
insert into #OptionsValues values
(1, 1, 'Oak'),
(2, 1, 'Beech'),
(3, 2, '10kg.'),
(4, 2, '12kg.'),
(5, 2, '13kg.'),
(6, 3, 'Ivory'),
(7, 3, 'Blue sky'),
(8, 4, '10cm.'),
(9, 4, '20cm.');
```

You can use STUFF((SELECT .... FOR XML PATH(''), 1,1,'') to get a concatenated column's values, delimited by some character (usually comma)

```
SELECT p.Name
       ,STUFF ((SELECT ', ' 
                       + Name 
                       + ': {'
                       + STUFF((SELECT ',' + Name
                               FROM #OptionsValues ov
                               WHERE ov.OptionId = o.OptionId
                               FOR xml path('')
                              ), 1, 1, '')
                       + '}'
                FROM #Options o
                WHERE o.ProductId = p.ProductId
                FOR xml path('')
              ), 1, 2, '') Options
FROM   #Products p;
```

The result is:

```
+-------+--------------------------------------------------+
|  Name |                      Options                     |
+-------+--------------------------------------------------+
|  Desk | Colour: {Oak,Beech}, Weight: {10kg.,12kg.,13kg.} |
+-------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Colour: {Ivory,Blue sky}, Width: {10cm.,20cm.}   |
+-------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Check it here: http://rextester.com/YBX28904

Comment: Ah, I see what you were getting at.
What I was hoping for was one row per option combination, something like:

    `Desk: Color=Oak, Weight=10Kg`
    `Desk: Color=Beech, Weight=10Kg`

However, I can see how your solution would work for the situation

Comment: If you edit your comment instead of add a new one, I don't receive any notification.

Comment: @DavidKemp For a one-row per option you must deal with a dynamic query. Is there a limited number of Options? All products have same number of options?